# Why setAttribute is not setting class to li

Tags: javascript, html, dom, attributes

Actually, I'm learning DOM Manipulation. As you can see, I created the li element but the issue is it is not applying the fontSize to the li.

```js
const title = document.querySelector("#main-heading");

title.style.color = "red";

const listItems = document.querySelectorAll(".list-items");
  
for (i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
    listItems[i].style.fontSize = "2rem";
}
const ul = document.querySelector("ul");
const li = document.createElement("li");

ul.append(li);
li.innerText = "X-men"
li.setAttribute('class' , 'list-items' )
```

```html
   <div class="container">
      <h1 id="main-heading">Favourite Movie</h1>
      <ul>
        <li class="list-items">The Matric</li>
        <li class="list-items">Star Wars</li>
        <li class="list-items">Harry Potter</li>
        <li class="list-items">Lord of the Rings</li>
        <li class="list-items">Marvel</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Works fine for me, but you have two different questions here so I'm not sure what's the issue

Comment: As you can see in the code snippet it is not working

Comment: @David-JSON your snippet does not show that `setAttribute` doesn't work. It shows the opposite - if you examine the HTML, you see `<li class="list-items">X-men</li>` thus the class *was* applied.

Comment: Yes it is showing i see it. But didn't work for me

Comment: The only problem I see in your code is that you are adding style directly to the existing items and then creating a new one without adding the style - which makes it smaller than the other

Comment: Yes i figure it out. It is working fine. I create the element li then i apply the style through loop. It is working okay now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove setting the font-size value inside `for` loop. Instead have it as separate css.

```
.list-items {
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

Append the newly created `li` after the class is added.

```
ul.append(li);
```

**Forked Example:**

```js
const title = document.querySelector("#main-heading");

title.style.color = "red";

const listItems = document.querySelectorAll(".list-items");
  
const ul = document.querySelector("ul");
const li = document.createElement("li");

li.innerText = "X-men"
li.setAttribute('class' , 'list-items');

ul.append(li);
```

```css
.list-items {
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <h1 id="main-heading">Favourite Movie</h1>
      <ul>
        <li class="list-items">The Matric</li>
        <li class="list-items">Star Wars</li>
        <li class="list-items">Harry Potter</li>
        <li class="list-items">Lord of the Rings</li>
        <li class="list-items">Marvel</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Cool. So what is the difference between setAttribute vs classList.add. Why setAttribute is not working here

Comment: They are both working

Comment: @David-JSON, Sorry both works, but usually I work with `classList.add` but I have changed to your way back and there is no issue with `setAttribute` but issue is that you are assigning the `fontSize` before the last `li` element is created so it doesn't work. Order matters here. My suggestion is to move the css declartion to the css file as given in the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The order you do things matters.

1. You find all the items matching `.list-items`
2. You change their font size
3. You create a new list item that matches `.list-items`

The item you create at step 3 didn't exist when you did the search at step 1 so wasn't changed by step 2.

---

Use a style sheet instead of inline style (which is what you modify with `...style.fontSize`.